# Swift press button function, press again for reverse

Tags: xcode, swift, button, boolean

I've got a simple IBAction that performs a method (let's just say shows subview). When I press this button again I want to perform another method (hides subview).

I have done the coding for the show/hide. I have tried using a Boolean but am unsure of the syntax. I also tried using an if/else statement like this:

```
var doubleTap = false

if (doubleTap) { 
    //hide view
} else {
    //show view
}
```

If someone could shed some light on this that'd be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change to code like below in the Button Press Method:

```
var doubleTap : Bool! = false
if (doubleTap) { 
    //Second Tap 
    doubleTap = false
} else {
    //First Tap 
    doubleTap = true
}
```

Comment: the `var doubleTap : Bool! = false` I declared at the top, outside of the button press method and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A function which is doing this in *one line*:

```
var toggled = true

func toggle() {
    toggled == true ? (toggled = false) : (toggled = true)
}
```

If you wanna let a button appear and disappear again this can be an approach:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewControllerClass : UIViewController {

  var buttonActive : Bool = true {
      didSet {
         self.mySubView.hidden = !self.mySubView.hidden
      }
    }

    func toggle() {
        buttonActive == true ? (buttonActive = false) : (buttonActive = true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a Global variable and intialize it to 1 and when it First time pressed intialize it to 1 in the function perform the task you want to do. Then if you presses it second time intialize it to 0 and then perform the other task